# How to create .exe file using Pyinstaller, which should accept command line argument while running with .exe

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have main.py file which will accept 2 arguments, create a setup.py file and use this file to create standalone application ie .exe file by using Pyinstaller as follows:

**main.py**:

```
import sys
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Display full name.')
parser.add_argument("-f", '--firstname', type=str, default='', help='first name.')
parser.add_argument("-l", '--lastname', type=str, default='', help='Last name.')
parsed_args = vars(parser.parse_args())
first_name = parsed_args['firstname']
last_name = parsed_args['lastname']
print("Hello " + first_name + " " + last_name)
```

**setup.py**:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os
sys.argv.append('py2exe')
firstname = 0
lastname = 0
if '--firstname' in sys.argv:
    index = sys.argv.index('--firstname')
    sys.argv.pop(index)
    upload = sys.argv.pop(index)
if '--lastname' in sys.argv:
    index = sys.argv.index('--lastname')
    sys.argv.pop(index)
    token = sys.argv.pop(index)
print("firstName:", firstname)
print("lastName:", lastname)
setup(
    console=['main.py'],
    script_args=[firstname, lastname],
)
```

I created setup.exe file by using command:

```
pyinstaller setup.py --onefile
```

I tried to execute the command as:

```
setup.exe --firstname "CLMSS" --lastname "BGMDDS"
```

Here I passed 2 arguments as like used while running main.py. So for this getting error as:

> The system cannot execute the specified program.

Can you help on this, How to resolve this issue? **OR** How to make as .exe file as accepting commands.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the solution you're looking for but for anyone else having trouble with this, I suggest you use `sys.argv[1]` to get the arguments instead of using argparse to get your arguments. It works just as well and plays very friendly with .exe execution on `cmd`